# WooCommerce remove_cart_item not removing items when logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, wordpress-rest-api

Playing around with WooCommerce, trying to call remove item in a custom api implementation.

I can successfully get a list of cart items and add items to the cart in similar fashion. Yet, despite the code being nearly identical on every guide I can find, I cannot get the cart item to be removed.

I get the cart items something like this:

```
$ret = array();
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $product = $values['data'];
    $p = array(
      'cart_item_key' => $item,
      'id' => $product->get_id(),
      'name' => $product->get_name(),
      'slug' => $product->get_slug(),
      'price' => $product->get_price(),
      'description' => $product->get_description(),
      'short_description' => $product->get_short_description(),
      'permalink' => get_permalink( $product->get_id() ),
      'quantity' => $values['quantity']
    );
    $ret[] = $p;
} 
return $ret;
```

Gives me a nice clean array back I can see in the response.

I then take the `cart_item_key` and pass it back in to another method like so:

```
$payload = $request->get_params();
$ret = array();
global $woocommerce;
if ($payload['cart_item_key']){
  $cartItemKey = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $payload['cart_item_key'] );
  $woocommerce->cart->remove_cart_item( $cartItemKey );

  unset( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$cartItemKey] );
}
return $ret;
```

I can see that `$payload['cart_item_key']` is indeed the string value I expect to see that passed into the call. I can also see that `$cartItemKey` is the *identical string value*, so I'm 99.8% certain that I have the right value to pass in.

The `remove_cart_item` and `unset` methods are two different implementations I've seen and neither seems to have an effect. I've also tried using `WC()` in place of the global `$woocommerce` to zero success. Whether I query the cart items again here and return them, or just refresh the page, all items are still in the cart.

There is **zero server caching** I'm aware of - everything I know about I have specifically turned off for this sandbox.

---

**Update**

This does appear to work as expected in a fresh session. For some reason, when I'm logged in as the admin for the site, I am unable to clear out my cart, and no errors are being logged for anything like this on the server.